# Orderby lowest result

Tags: php, laravel

I'm having problem with results order.
I'm having this models.

Championship:

```
public function tours()

{
    return $this->hasMany(Tour::class, 'championship_id', 'id');
}

public function attempts()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Attempt::class, 'championship_id', 'id');
}
```

Tour:

```
public function championship()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Championship::class, 'championship_id', 'id');
}

public function brackets()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Bracket::class, 'bracket_tour');
}

public function rounds()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Round::class, 'tour_id', 'id');
}

public function attempts()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Attempt::class, 'tour_id', 'id');
}
```

Bracket:

```
public function students()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Student::class, 'bracket_student');
}

public function attempts()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Attempt::class, 'bracket_id', 'id');
}

public function tours()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Tour::class, 'bracket_tour');
}
```

Student:

```
public function school()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(School::class, 'school_id', 'id');
}

public function brackets()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Bracket::class, 'bracket_student');
}

public function attempts()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Attempt::class, 'attempt_id', 'id');
}

public function rounds()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Round::class, 'student_id', 'id');
}
```

Round:

```
public function attempts()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Attempt::class, 'round_id', 'id');
}

public function tour()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Tour::class, 'tour_id', 'id');
}

public function student()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Student::class, 'student_id', 'id');
}
```

Attempt:

```
public function championship()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Championship::class, 'championship_id', 'id');
}

public function bracket()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Bracket::class, 'bracket_id', 'id');
}

public function student()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Student::class, 'attempt_id', 'id');
}

public function tour()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Tour::class, 'tour_id', 'id');
}

public function round()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Round::class, 'round_id', 'id');
}
```

Blade:

```
<body>
    <div class="main-result container">
        @foreach($championships as $championship)
        @if($championship->deleted)
        @else
        <div class="championship-collapse">
            <button class="btn btn-primary championship-collapse-button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#championshipCollapse-{{ $championship->id }}" role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">{{ $championship->name }}</button>
        </div>
        @endif
        <div class="collapse" id="championshipCollapse-{{ $championship->id }}">
            <div class="select-main-result">
                @foreach($championship->tours as $tour)
                @if($tour->deleted)
                @else
                <div class="tour-collapse">
                    <button class="btn btn-primary tour-collapse-button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#tourCollapse-{{ $tour->id }}" role="button" aria-expanded="false">{{ $tour->name }}</button>
                </div>
                @endif
                <div class="collapse" id="tourCollapse-{{ $tour->id }}">
                    <div class="select-main-result">
                        @foreach($tour->brackets as $bracket)
                        @if($bracket->deleted)
                        @else
                        <div class="group-collapse">
                            <button class="btn btn-primary group-collapse-button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#groupCollapse-{{$tour->id}}{{ $bracket->id }}" role="button" aria-expanded="false">{{ $bracket->name }}</button>
                        </div>
                        @endif
                        <div class="collapse" id="groupCollapse-{{$tour->id}}{{ $bracket->id }}">
                            <div class="select-main-result main-result-table">
                                <div class="table-responsive main-result-table-content">
                                    <table class="table table-striped table-dark main-result-table-wrapper">
                                        <thead class="">
                                            <tr>
                                                <th class="col-xs-1 main-result-heading-text">place</th>
                                                <th class="col-xs-2 main-result-heading-text">name</th>
                                                <th class="col-xs-2 main-result-heading-text">gender</th>
                                                <th class="col-xs-2 main-result-heading-text">birthday</th>
                                                <th class="col-xs-2 main-result-heading-text">school</th>
                                                <th class="col-xs-1 main-result-heading-text">round 1</th>
                                                <th class="col-xs-1 main-result-heading-text">round 2</th>
                                                <th class="col-xs-2 main-result-heading-text border-0">result</th>
                                            </tr>
                                        </thead>
                                        <tbody class="" id="tabs-{{$bracket->id}}">
                                            @foreach($bracket->students as $student)
                                            @if($student->deleted)
                                            @else
                                            <tr class="randomaized" student_id="" bracket_id="1">
                                                <th class="col-xs-1 name-lastname border-right">1</th>
                                                <th class="col-xs-2 name-lastname border-right">{{$student->first_name}} {{$student->last_name}}</th>
                                                <th class="col-xs-2 gender border-right">{{$student->gender}}</th>
                                                <th class="col-xs-2 birthday-year border-right">{{Carbon\Carbon::parse($student->birthday)->format('d.m.Y')}}</th>
                                                <th class="col-xs-2 school border-right">{{$student->school->name}}</th>
                                                @foreach($student->rounds as $round)
                                                @if($round->deleted)
                                                @else
                                                <th class="col-xs-1 round-1 border-right">{{$round->attempt_one}}</th>
                                                <th class="col-xs-1 round-2 border-right">{{$round->attempt_two}}</th>
                                                @endif
                                                @foreach($round->attempts as $attempt)
                                                @if($attempt->deleted)
                                                @else
                                                <th class="col-xs-1 final-result border-right">{{$attempt->result}}</th>
                                                @endif
                                                @endforeach
                                                @endforeach
                                            </tr>
                                            @endif
                                            @endforeach
                                        </tbody>
                                    </table>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        @endforeach
                    </div>
                </div>
                @endforeach
            </div>
        </div>
        @endforeach
    </div>
</body>
```

Everything is working but order must be by result.
lowest result must be first. I'm trying to add everywhere order by result < '' but it is not working so where i must add it?
And another question is my model set are currect?

Comment: For correct order using child table you should use join as per your requirement

Comment: How to do that ?

Comment: Example is : $users = DB::table('users')
            ->leftJoin('posts', 'users.id', '=', 'posts.user_id')
            ->get();

Comment: Thanks for answer. I have one more question, If  student is not added in rounds table button must be displayed but if he is in rounds table button must be visible    if($student->rounds)
                        <button></button>
                        else
                        
                      endif  but when i do this its showing on all students

Comment: use right join for that

Comment: Okay right join. and what about  button ?

Comment: $students = Student::all()->join('attempts', 'student.id', '=', 'attempts.result');  it's don't working